# Access result Set after closing connection with db

Tags: java, sqlite, resultset

```
public ResultSet Connections() {

    try {
        conn = this.connect();
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        //  String sql = "Select * from connections";
        String sql = "SELECT name , pass , ip , port , dbName , dbType FROM connections";
        rsc = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        rsc.next();

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("Conns error " + ex);

    }
    return rsc;
}
```

I need to close the connection with db and retrieve the data from the resultset. But if i close it before the return statement cant access the Resultset in the end.

Comment: That is not possible. You can extract your result into some variable and then close the connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't return a `ResultSet` keep it open just long enough and then close it. The best would be to read it into another datastructure, like a `List` and then return said list:

Also I would recommend to use *try-with-resources*-statements:

```
public List<Connections> Connections() {
    String sql = "SELECT name , pass , ip , port , dbName , dbType FROM connections";

    try(Connection conn = this.connect(); 
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement()
        ResultSet rsc = stmt.executeQuery(sql)) {
        List<Connections> list = new ArrayList<>();
        while(rsc.next()){
            list.add(new Connections(
                rsc.getString("name"),
                rsc.getString("pass"),
                rsc.getInt("ip"),
                rsc.getInt("port"),
                rsc.getString("dbName"),
                rsc.getInt("dbType")
            ));
        }
        return list;
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("Conns error " + ex);
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

Where your `Connections` class would somewhat look like this:

```
public class Connections{

    // fields

    public Connections(String name, String pass, int ip, int port, String dbName, int dbType){
         // assing parameters to fields
    }

    // getters and setters
}
```

Comment: This solved my problem even thou i have to change some of my other methods.

Comment: @LotusPrime glad I have helped. Keeping a ResultSet open over a long period of time, is mostly bad design. So it is probably better to refactor your code now, than to have resource leaks and unexpected Bugs later in the application

Answer (score -1):

As far i know the better way is to add `finally` clause in `trycatch` and close your connection there. And also it would be better if you throw your error through your method. eg

```
    public ResultSet Connections() throws SQLException {

        try {
            conn = this.connect();
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            //  String sql = "Select * from connections";
            String sql = "SELECT name , pass , ip , port , dbName , dbType FROM connections";
            rsc = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            rsc.next();

            return rsc;

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            throw new SQLException(ex.getMessage());

        } finally {
          //your connection closing code here
          conn.close();//it depends upon your code
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't have a problem. OP has: *But if i close it before the return statement cant access the Resultset in the end.* The `finally` will be called after the `return` statement. So the resultSet will also be closed then

Comment: It means you didn't get any results

Comment: I am sorry, but this is wrong. The ResultSet, once closed, will throw an exception, so there might be results but not available anymore, as it is closed